# Does Azure charge for number of app services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Does Azure charge only for the utilization of App service plan resources or for the number of app services we create under that App service plan? Does the number of app services created under a app service plan effects cost?

I am developing a microservices project and I am unsure of whether to deploy each microservice in a dedicated app service or deploying all in one app service as virtual directories. Cost is a concern for our project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does Azure charge only for the utilization of App service plan resources or for the number of app services we create under that App service plan?

Ignoring the Free and Shared tiers, you'll pay only for the [App Service **Plan**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) (cost per selected machine size x number of instances). You'll pay the same whether you have 0 or 50 Apps on the Service plan (although any other I/O, Storage etc consumed by those Apps will be additional).

(Whereas the free tier allows a max of 10 Apps, and the Shared tier allows 100 Apps)

In theory you can then add as many **App** Services (apps, e.g. Web Apps, Services, Function Apps etc) as you like on each App Service Plan, however in practice you'll be limited by the overall resources of the VM size and plan you've selected (e.g. [10GB Disk space on Basic](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/), and a B1 only has 1.75GB RAM).

From the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#should-i-put-an-app-in-a-new-plan-or-an-existing-plan), the recommendation is:

> Isolate your app into a new App Service plan when:
>
> - The app is resource-intensive.
> - You want to scale the app independently from the other apps in the existing plan.
> - The app needs resource in a different geographical region.

I would also add the opinion:

- If applicable, keep your environments (Dev, UAT, Prod) isolated, either at App Service Plan level, or consider isolation at Resource Group or Subscription level.
- Unless your apps are maxing out CPU usage, while installing as many apps per Service Plan as makes logical sense, but monitor performance and the resource usage on the VM instances as you go.
- In my situation, I've typically found that RAM to be the bottleneck, so I would typically try to scale up to a VM size with more RAM to host more Apps before separating out the Apps and adding more Service Plans.
- If you are on .Net Core or another stack which doesn't need Windows, I would recommend looking into the Linux Service Plans - they are considerably cheaper than Windows instances.
  <del>One caveat - as at present, there's a weird limitation which doesn't allow mixing of Windows and Linux Service Plans [in the same resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations)</del> [As of Jan 2021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview#limitations) you can deploy both Windows and Linux App Service plans to the same resource group, but note that [some VS versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161717/cant-create-windows-and-linux-app-service-plans-in) might still incorrectly enforce this as a validation rule if you are deploying via publish.
- Each App is logically fairly well isolated on the Service Plan instances, so you can add, delete, restart, and deploy apps without interfering with the others.
- Although Docker containers can be deployed as an App Service, you might find [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/) a better fit.

**And More Detail**

The terminology around the Azure Managed App Service Plans is somewhat confusing, but to clarify:

- An App Service Plan (Service Plan) can have 1 or more managed VM instances
  e.g. 1 Service Plan scaled to 3 Instances = 3 VMs to pay for.
- Ignoring the Free / Shared tier (on the shared tier you pay for each App), and also ignoring the Isolated tier, you'll pay a fixed monthly cost for each Instance
- You can add multiple Apps to each App Service Plan - e.g. Web Apps, Function Apps, Misc. Console Apps, and Docker images. These will be deployed to all instances in the plan.
- On the Standard tier and above, you can configure [Deployment Slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) on your Apps, which provides the ability to smoke-test and provide continued uptime during deployments, especially in your production environment. Like any deployed app, deploying to a Deployment slot will consume cpu, memory and io resources.

FWIW App Service Plans (microsoft.web/serverfarms) account for approximately 40% of our overall Monthly Azure costs

This cost can quickly multiply, especially if you are running multiple isolated environments (Dev, UAT, Prod etc) and if you need to scale out to more than one instance per environment for redundancy or scale reasons.

As at time of writing, indicative VM instance costs on US East are approximately

- Dev B1 1.75GB RAM are ~$15pm Linux / ~$50pm Windows
- Prod P1V2 3.5GB RAM are ~$80 Linux / ~$150pm Windows

So it's only natural to try and minimize costs by deploying multiple apps to a single VM, especially in a fine-grained Microservice enterprise or system.

Comment: I never even considered running netcore web apps on Linux. Brilliant! It looks like you're spot-on for Linux being cheaper for the Basic and Premium SKUs. But for SKUs in the Standard pricing tier, the prices are roughly equivalent.

Comment: Just noting that as of now, Windows and Linux plans can be deployed into the same resource group.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can save cost by hosting [`multiple apps`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) in one app service plan. You do not need a separate web app plan for each web app.

Generally the price you pay is for the app service plan and not the web app (Exception here is the shared plan) so your costs do not increase as you add more applications to the same plan.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to this that if you have an app that is memory intensive, I would definitely isolate it to its own App Service Plan. Since usage limits are at the plan level, you don't want to get errors for mission critical apps due to a runaway app or an app experiencing higher traffic. Another good tip is to set up auto scaling with rules you define by your needs, this will prevent downtime if higher traffic than what the plan allocates is experienced.

Though yes, money can definitely be saved by grouping apps together in the same plan.